# Error in AWS Glue-Spark job while processing small number of records

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

My Spark(AWS Glue) program pulls data from Snowflake and do few transformations. But, i am getting error - "org.apache.spark.shuffle.fetchfailedexception stream is corrupted"

The job processes less than 400K records using Glue job (Spark SQL,Scala) with below transformations.

1. Group by on Table1 (~ 60K Records)
2. left Join above results with Table 2 (300K records)
3. left Join above result with Table 3 (50K records)

The Glue worker type is G.2x and number of workers are 10.

I try to persist the data initially, but still did not work. So, the only work around i found(assuming shuffle is causing this issue) is, store the intermediate results of program in S3 bucket and read data from S3 and do remaining transformations, which complete the job quickly. All happened in single Glue job.

Is it a right approach? or any other suggestion?